# Send command to USB device (FingerPrint Scanner) with no driver for Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, usb

I am trying to create an application with remote controlling a [Fingerprint sensor](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/fingerprint-scanner-gt-521fxx-hookup-guide) (Guide included on link) for enrolling and identifying fingerprints on are Raspberry PI 3 Model.
There is a SDK_DEMO for this particular functionality on Windows only, which you can find in the Guile I mentioned above.

- SDK_DEMO is written in C++ on Visual studio so I can't manipulate the code to run it on Raspberry Pi 3.

From the SDK_DEMO source code I figured out which command I need to send to execute tasks.

The Commands

```
CMD_NONE                = 0x00,
CMD_OPEN                = 0x01,
CMD_CLOSE               = 0x02,
CMD_USB_INTERNAL_CHECK  = 0x03,
CMD_CHANGE_BAUDRATE     = 0x04,
CMD_MODULE_INFO         = 0x06,

CMD_CMOS_LED            = 0x12,

CMD_ENROLL_COUNT        = 0x20,
CMD_CHECK_ENROLLED      = 0x21,
CMD_ENROLL_START        = 0x22,
CMD_ENROLL              = 0x23,
CMD_ENROLL1             = 0x23,
CMD_ENROLL2             = 0x24,
CMD_ENROLL3             = 0x25,
CMD_IS_PRESS_FINGER     = 0x26,

CMD_DELETE              = 0x40,
CMD_DELETE_ALL          = 0x41,

CMD_VERIFY              = 0x50,
CMD_IDENTIFY            = 0x51,
CMD_VERIFY_TEMPLATE     = 0x52,
CMD_IDENTIFY_TEMPLATE   = 0x53,

CMD_CAPTURE             = 0x60,

CMD_GET_IMAGE           = 0x62,
CMD_GET_RAWIMAGE        = 0x63,

CMD_GET_TEMPLATE        = 0x70,
CMD_ADD_TEMPLATE        = 0x71,
CMD_GET_DATABASE_START  = 0x72,
CMD_GET_DATABASE_END    = 0x73,

CMD_FW_UPDATE           = 0x80,
CMD_ISO_UPDATE          = 0x81,
CMD_FAKE_DETECTOR       = 0x91,

CMD_SET_SECURITY_LEVEL  = 0xF0,
CMD_GET_SECURITY_LEVEL  = 0xF1,

ACK_OK                  = 0x30,
NACK_INFO               = 0x31,
```

SKD_DEMO recognised the FingerPrint sensor as Mass Storage and somehow was running the commands like that.

In Ubuntu though when I plug in the usb device I don't get any Mass storage mounting and on `lsusb`  I get this:

[image]

I have be searching about this and tried to

```
echo "0x12" >> /dev/bus/usb/001/008
```

But I got a write error for invalid argument.

Here are the terminal commands for the echo attempt:

[image]

Is there a way I can send raw commands with this format and executing actions without needing to write a  driver for this USB device on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can work like that. For one thing `echo "0x012...` sent the literal string of ascii characters `0x12` which is only a base-16 representation of the actual binary data needed to communicate with the device.

Have a look into python perhaps (you could use a lot of other languages to do this as well, however Python is usually a good place to start) and communicating with USB devices. Maybe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290837/how-to-interact-with-usb-device-using-pyusb

Answer (score 0):

You should write `/dev/bus/usb/[vid:pid]`. `vid` and `pid` are the numbers  written near the ID. In your case you can try this command:

```
echo "0x12" >> /dev/bus/usb/001/2009:7638
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since your answer is in conflict to remarks in [the previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476556/377345), please indicate how your solution addresses this or in what way the other answer is in error. Also, usually the files under `/dev/bus/usb` are not named according to the `VID:PID` scheme but rather by bus number/consecutive device number (see e.g.[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121399/377345)).

Comment: That "0x12" is most likely an ASCII representation of a byte value encoded as hexadecimal. Even if this were the right way to address the device the command is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK_DEMO seems to use a COM port for connecting to the fingerprint scanner in Windows, and the tutorial indicates that the use of a USB-to-serial converter is the expected way. Since the command set includes both `CMD_GET_TEMPLATE` and `CMD_ADD_TEMPLATE`, possibly for reading & writing fingerprint templates to the scanner respectively, it might be that the SDK_DEMO was actually *implementing* the mass storage emulation.

In your picture of your `lsusb` listing (BTW please don't attach pictures of text; just copy&paste the actual text if at all possible) the `Bus 001 Device 008` device seems to have the USB vendor & product IDs of `2009:7638`.

Unfortunately the USB vendor ID `2009` [seems to refer to iStorage](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/2009), and on that vendor, only a few flash drive IDs are known to exist.

On the other hand, the IDs of USB-to-serial converter chips are often configurable, as when such a chip is used as part of a larger product, the vendor of the larger product would wish it to have their own vendor & product codes. So first you must find out if the USB device with IDs `2009:7638` is indeed a USB serial converter with a custom ID, or is it something different.

To do that, please run the command `lsusb -d 2009:7638 -v` while the device is connected. If the output includes lines like this, it is definitely a USB-to-serial converter:

```
  bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
  bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  iInterface              2 USB Serial Converter
```

But if the device actually provides a USB Mass Storage interface, then the output will include either a `bDeviceClass` or `bInterfaceClass` line with the value of `8 Mass Storage`. If so, then the device should also appear in `lsblk` output.

If the USB-to-serial converter chip is a FTDI product (as suggested by the guide you linked), the correct driver module for it is probably `ftdi_sio`. To load the module and make it aware of the custom IDs:

```
modprobe ftdi_sio
echo 2009 7638 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id
```

The same strategy can be used with other USB-to-serial driver modules, too; just replace the name of the module in both commands.

If you are unable to identify the correct driver module, please run `lsusb -d 2009:7638 -v > /tmp/usbserial-info.txt` and edit your question to add the contents of the resulting `/tmp/usbserial-info.txt` file into it.

If the USB-to-serial driver recognizes the device, a `/dev/ttyUSB0` device node should now appear. This would be the device to use for communicating with the fingerprint scanner.

The `/dev/bus/usb/xxx/yyy` devices like the `/dev/bus/usb/001/008` you tried to use are designed to be used with [`libusb`](https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/), since they require the application using the device node to be aware of different *USB endpoints* and *USB transfer modes*. A single USB device will have at least one *control endpoint* and may have multiple *interfaces*, each with multiple endpoints.

The `/dev/bus/usb/...` device nodes allow the full feature set of USB to be used, but because of this, they are not really usable by scripts; basically these device nodes exist to be a target for specific system calls, not for simply piping data in and out of them.